# Prevent addition of parens when tab-completing method group

Tags: c#, resharper, resharper-9.0

I'm currently using Resharper 9.0 and if I've got code like the following:

```
public void DoSomething(Func<string, int> func);

public int SomeMethod(string input);

DoSomething(SomeMethod);
```

If I start typing the `SomeMethod` method group in the `DoSomething` call, and hit tab to complete the symbol, Resharper introduces unnecessary parentheses:

```
DoSomething(SomeMethod());
```

Which of course is a compile-error because `SomeMethod` takes an argument.

I've had a look around online and a hunt in Resharper's settings, but I can't seem to find a way to prevent this.

Comment: @GrantWinney I'm almost **certain** it's buried in configuration somewhere, it's just finding **where**

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested this scenario with 9.1.1 and I can't recreate it. Perhaps try updating (9.1.1 is a free upgrade to 9.0)?